# Offscreen UIButton action not triggered - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, addtarget

I have two `UIButton`'s created off screen that are animated onto the screen when a button is pressed. However, neither of the button's target functions are never called, as I believe the buttons are not being "pressed". The buttons do work if I simply create them on the screen, so I believe the issue is related to the buttons being animated onto the screen from outside the screens bounds.

**Edit:** The buttons do animate onto the screen properly and are visible, however pressing them does nothing.

**Code:**

```
var isMenuOpen : Bool = false
var button_height : CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/8

var button_view : UIView!
var mylists : UIButton!
var settings : UIButton!

@IBAction func openMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, self.button_height * (self.isMenuOpen ? 0 : -1))
    }, completion: {finished in
        self.isMenuOpen = !self.isMenuOpen
    })

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initButtons()  
}

func initButtons() {
    button_view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0.0, y:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height, width:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height:button_height))
    button_view.userInteractionEnabled = true

    mylists = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2.0, height:button_height))
    mylists.setTitle("My Lists", forState: .Normal)
    mylists.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 105/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 1.0)
    mylists.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showLists(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    button_view.addSubview(mylists)

    settings = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2.0, y:0.0, width:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2.0, height:button_height))
    settings.setTitle("Settings", forState: .Normal)
    settings.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 135/255, green: 205/255, blue: 236/255, alpha: 1.0)
    settings.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSettings(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    button_view.addSubview(settings)

    self.view.addSubview(button_view)
}

func showLists(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("showLists")
}

func showSettings(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("showSettings")
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't the exact goal of your transition, but it looks like the view that is holding the buttons `button_view` is never being transition onto the screen.

Are you trying to make each button go to the screen or are you trying to make both buttons go to the screen inside a container (`button_view_`)? If you are trying to do both, I would recommend doing

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.button_view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -1*(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
}, completion: {finished in
    self.isMenuOpen = !self.isMenuOpen
})
```

This is based off the assumption you are trying to move the box to the screen as a whole.

Edit:

Ahh! I see what is happening! So you are moving self.view up, which you never wanna move a UIViewController.view. Move a container of the view. So instead of moving self.view, move button_view. Moving a UIController.view removes all of the underneath layers and functionality of a UIViewController

Comment: The buttons are visible after the animation though. Wouldn't that mean that their container would also be on the screen?

Comment: So visible but not clickable?

Comment: Correct and the buttons never highlight when pressed so I assume they're disabled or their frame is off screen somehow, but debugging and `print` statements have gotten me nowhere.

Comment: Well what you are doing is moving the self.view out of the way, and then you are moving menu_button. Both of which have zero regards toward either of the other 2 buttons, or the view containing them. So I am not sure how you can see them.

Comment: `button_view`, which contains both buttons, is a subview of `self.view`

Comment: Ahh! I see what is happening! 

So you are moving self.view up, which you never wanna move a UIViewController.view. Move a container of the view. So instead of moving self.view, move button_view. Moving a UIController.view removes all of the underneath layers and functionality of a UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks. That somewhat fixed the issue.  If you update your answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Well would you like help with anything else? Just update your question and I can look at whatever else is causing issues.

Comment: My other issue was that there were other components in the view that I wished to be animated up with the view. I solved this, however, by animating each of the view's subviews upwards like I do with the buttons and leaving the view alone. Thanks tho.

Comment: Well if you added them to a container, such as button_view, then just animate the container, and they would all go with it! I have been taught that containers are very useful, especially in situations of animations and grouping.